# Send message from python to Google Chrome on Windows and tell it to export or import bookmarks

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, automation

I am running on Windows. I want to have a Python program send a message to Google Chrome and tell it to import or export bookmarks. [This can be done through the Chrome user interface](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en), but I don't know how to do it programmatically.

Comment: [Could this be what you are looking for ?](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks) This information is only available through ChromeExtensions

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to do it through a Python API, not a Chrome Extension.